# How do I change where a Powershell module is installed?

Tags: powershell

I am using version 3.0 and there doesn't seem to be a way to specify a default folder where all your modules are installed. In particular, I am trying to install Posh-Git, but it insists on installing the modules in MyDocuments\WindowsPowershell.  How do I change this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, PowerShell looks for modules in one of two locations, both are specified in the 
PSModulePath environment variable.

```
   System modules: %windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
   Current user modules:  %UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
```

You can add your own module directory to the path:

```
$env:PSModulePath+=';c:\MyModules'
```

Comment: I don't get it. This only changes where Powershell looks for modules, not where they are installed?